# How to call "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before "WebSecurity" class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to seed membership into my asp.net mvc application (in the migrations/config.cs file)

```
protected override void Seed(Logintest.Models.ApplicationDbContext 
context)
    {
        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

        if(!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        }
        if(membership.GetUser("jay", false) == null)
        {
            membership.CreateUserAndAccount("jay", "otoole");
        }
        if(!roles.GetRolesForUser("jay").Contains("Admin"))
        {
            roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "jay" }, new[] { "admin" });
        }
    }
```

I also enabled the Role Manager and the Membership Manager in Web.config

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider,
         WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider,
         WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Although when I try to Update-Database in Package Manager Console in order to run the Seed method, I get the following error:

> You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method 
>   before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call 
>   should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

I can not find the _AppStart.cshtml file so I created it and placed the following in it:

```
@using System.Configuration;
@{  
   WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", 
   "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
}
```

After trying the above I still get the same error. Can someone please point me in the right direction? i.e. how do I call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before the "WebSecurity" class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after messing around with the code, I added the initialize database call at the top of the seed() method and it works fine

```
protected override void Seed(Logintest.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", 
          "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

        if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        }
        if (membership.GetUser("jay", false) == null)
        {
            membership.CreateUserAndAccount("jay", "otoole");
        }
        if (!roles.GetRolesForUser("jay").Contains("Admin"))
        {
            roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "jay" }, new[] { "admin" });
        }
    }
```